# Populating a list in python using for loop

Tags: python

```
a = int(input())
l1 = []
for i in range(a):
    l1[i] = 5

print(l1)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
list assignment index out of range
```

`i` will always be smaller than `a` so why am I getting this error? I don't wish to use `append()`.

Comment: *"I don't wish to use append()"* Why?

Comment: The error occurs because `l1` has length zero, so you cant index into `l[i]` for any `i`. Why you don't want to use `append` is beyond me.

Comment: i have solved the issue using append() but wish to learn how to populate lists in python without using append()

Comment: python List is different from Arrays. So stop treating List like Arrays.

Comment: `append()` is the one obvious way to do it. Using anything else would make for worse code.

Comment: Just try list comprehension as `l1 = [5 for _ in range(10)]` and `print (l1)` if you are so against the `append()`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Check my answer.

Comment: @VishalSingh: why? shouldn't he use an index??

Comment: thanks Aran i understand what you are trying to say , understood the problem.

Comment: you can simply use the following line to initialize the list `l1 = [None] * a`

Comment: @blue_note: you can only access elements but cannot insert new elements using index.

Comment: @VishalSingh: that's true of arrays too

Comment: @blue_note: there would be no error in array[0]=someValue if it were to be an array of any other language.

Comment: @VishalSingh: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` in java.

Comment: @blue_note: you are only declaring an array but not initializing it. int[] Array = new int[20] try now

Comment: @VishalSingh: that's not an empty array. It's an array of zeros

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179328/discussion-between-vishal-singh-and-blue-note).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this if you want to get a list of *n* '5' elements:

```
a = int(input())
l1 = [5 for _ in range(a)]
print l1
```

It will wait for input and save the list in the *l1* list

Comment: I would replace `i` by `_` since it's not being used here

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert`.

```
a = int(input())
l1 = []
for i in range(a):
    l1.insert(999999999999,5)

print(l1)
```

Executing:

```
 10
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the `i`-th element, but your list is empty. It *has to* have a `i`-th element to write `a[i] = 5`. So, populate your list with a dummy value. eg, start with `l1 = [None] * a` instead of `l1 = []`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing the behavior of list to dictionary. Dictionary would work.

```
a = int(input())
l1 = {}
for i in range(a):
    l1[i] = 5  

print([j for i,j in l1.items()])
```

You got an error because there exists no element at l1[0] to be assigned users input. If we were to make your code work, we need to pre-populate the list with dummies.

```
a = int(input())
l1 = (','*(a-1)).split(',')
for i in range(a):
    l1[i] = 5

print(l1)
```

Comment: I don't think he is confused between Dictionary and List. He is treating List like Arrays, maybe he just started python and trying to apply other Language paradigms in Python

Comment: Ah! Would not array throw IndexError?

Comment: python doesn't have arrays. If arrays were to initialize then no they won't throw error if you do array[0]=someValue

Comment: I was think of numpy: I.e. l1 = np.array([]). This throws IndexError ;)

Comment: @VishalSingh Python *does* have arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the simplest change is to append the elements, rather than use an index.  The list doesn't need to be pre-sized and the code is easy to read for someone coming from another language.  Replace "i" with "_" if you like.

```
a = int(input())
l1 = []
for i in range(a):
    l1.append(5)

print(l1)
```